# Python: base class overwrites methods of child class

Tags: python, delegates, overriding

I'm facing an issue where I want to "forward"/delegate a certain set of methods from the base class *A* to methods of the object *alpha*, however, when inheriting from it (class *B*) and overriding the methods, the methods implemented in class *B* are ignored and only those of the base class are called.

I was wondering if it's possible to do this in a non-dynamic way to allow autocompletion by the IDE?

```
class Alpha:
   def foo(self):
      print('foo alpha')


class A:
   def __init__(self):
      self.alpha = Alpha()
      self.foo = self.alpha.foo


class B(A):
   def foo(self):
      print('foo b')
      super().foo()


b = B()
b.foo()  # prints 'foo alpha' instead of 'foo b' and 'foo alpha'
```

I know I could just define a method foo in class A like:

```
class A:
   def foo(self): 
      self.alpha.foo()
```

Yet, I want to "forward" multiple methods, therefore, I wanted to spare some lines of code (additionally I don't need functools.wrap() to preserve the method's docstring and type annotations)

Another approach which didn't work for me was to check (via `dir(self)`) if the method already exists (because it's implemented in a child class) and only add the forwarding otherwise, because I want to be able to call `super().foo()` from within B.foo

Comment: So what's the expected behaviour? Should `A` forward all the missing method calls to `Alpha`? Only a defined set?

Comment: Yes all the missing calls (i.e. of a subclass C inheriting A but not implementing foo()) should be forwarded to Alpha and each method in subclasses overriding foo sould call super().foo() as well

Comment: Okay, but let's say I wanna call `A.bar`. Does it try to forward it as well if `A` does not define `bar`?

Comment: No it should only work when explizitly specified

Comment: Can someone explain WHY `B`'s `foo` method does not override `A`'s ? I'm very fuzzy on class inheritance mechanisms.

Comment: But it does. Except that `foo` is overwritten at run time in the `__init__` method.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand: **class** B's foo method overrides any ancestor class' foo method, but then when **instance** b is created the foo method is overridden by A's `__init__()` ?